# Some thread questions

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Lets say I have a program like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        new Task(() => {
            NewClass class = new NewClass();
        }).Start();
    }
}

class NewClass {
    public NewClass() {
        new Task(() => {
            someMethod();
        }).Start();
    }

    public void someMethod() {/* Do stuff */}
}
```

Will the first thrad quit after creating the new object `class` or will it go on running?

If the object is deleted (class = null) will the second thread cancel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. Your tasks will finish quickly depending on your implementation in someMethod(). Let's assume that it is Thead.Delay() with a large delay.

You Task will end when your Main method ends - so quite quickly. Add a Console.ReadKey() to solve that.

If you no longer reference the NewClass object anywhere in the system, it will eventually be Garbage Collected, but that has no bearing on the Task. If the Task references the object, it will be kept in memory. In other words - you can't delete it.

Also, Task != Thread. If you create 100 tasks you will most likely not end up with 100 threads.

Comment: So the first Task will quit very fast right after its done whats inside its block? But the second Task can run a long time depending on the someMethod() ?

Comment: The tasks will have no knowledge of eachother, and the outer task will not wait for the inner task to finish if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the first thrad quit after creating the new object class or will it go on running?

Who knows. Tasks are not threads. The task ends, but the thread may pick up another task, as per task scheduler.

> If the object is deleted (class = null)

That does not delete the object at all. The object is still there. There is no way to delete an object in C# - that is left to the GC.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the first thrad quit after creating the new object class or will it go on running?

The thread used by the task comes from the thread pool. Once the task is complete, the thread will be returned to the thread pool to do some other work.

> If the object is deleted (class = null) will the second thread cancel?

No, it will have no effect on the second thread. Setting a variable to null doesn't "delete" the object... it just removes a reference to it.

Comment: Is it possible to remove an object from memory?

Comment: @Arbitur, no, not explicitly. It's done by the garbage collector when there object isn't referenced anymore.